# iMessage notifications with current date and time from years ago

Tags: iphone, icloud, messages

Recently, I’ve been receiving texts with current time stamps from a while ago. A new Mac that had been connected to iCloud and that’s what is receiving them. I have no idea what’s going on; I can figure things out myself most the time.

It doesn’t come up on my iPhone or Apple Watch; only on the Mac so I’m assuming it’s just iCloud but that doesn’t explain the current time and date.

Any help diagnosing what’s going on would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the (redacted, if necessary) message from both devices?  I’m only interested in the date/time stamp where on the device it shows “a long time ago” and on the Mac it shows current.

Comment: It only shows up on Mac though, so not sure about that. I wipe my conversations after 30 days and this was nearly 2 years ago but it’s coming up as sent and received Wednesday evening.

Comment: When you say “wiped,” do you mean deleted from your phone?  And this was done years ago?  Were you syncing to iCloud messages back then? I’m trying to replicate with an old phone I have sitting here, but there are no messages to sync.  This might be a bug that should be reported to Apple.I

Comment: I honestly have no clue. I saw a thread around the same time years ago I synced where it was happening then but nothing recent. I haven’t updated iOS in a year maybe longer too. 

I have that “keep for 30 days” thing on so no clue what happens. 

I used iCloud a lot back then and stopped it coz if max storage. Will have to contact Apple and find out.

Comment: Spoke to Apple. Said it’s a desync and happens every so often when devices aren’t updated on newest software with matching iCloud software? Confusing but that’s what support agent said.

Comment: It's a valid answer.  Post it as such and ping me here (use @Allan) and I'll vote it up!